# E_INVALIDARG Exception in this particular argument

Tags: c#, excel

Accessing a single range in Excel works fine. But when trying to access range of cells, I've got an invalid argument exception (E_INVALIDARG).
[image]

Comment: You need to use `.Range`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx

Comment: @RonBeyer. Yes! I am actually using range. I can get a reference to cells with this Range["A"] or Range[row, col] but not with this one Range["A1:A!0']. And BTW, wks is an instance of Worksheet interface and Cells is, of course, its property of Range type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a work around. I don't know if this can a permanent solution. Any way:[image]

I just stored my Worksheet variable (wks) to a dynamic variable (dwks) and finally achieved what I want. BTW, I just found out Cells won't work even in the dynamic variable; Range does. But range, unless I called it via dynamic variable, throws that E_INVALIDARG error.